# Display Local Notifications In A NativeScript Application With Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

maybe someone knows how to display local notification only if the program is in the background, if my chat page is open then you do not need to display anything.
This code works for me, but I need it if the chat page opens that no notification come. Someone can help? and is this behavior possible?

```
 LocalNotifications.hasPermission().then(
        function (granted) {
            if(granted === true) {
                LocalNotifications.schedule([{
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Information',
                    body: 'Test',
                    badge: 1,
                    at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (10 * 1000))
                }]);
            } else {
                dialogs.alert({
                    title: "Information",
                    message: "You need to give permission to notification",
                    okButtonText: "OK"
                })
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Take a look at the new [Notification object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/notification)

Answer (score 1):

1) First add **NativeScript Local Notifications Plugin**

`tns plugin add nativescript-local-notifications`

2) **notification.component.ts file**

// import

`import { alert } from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";`

`import { LocalNotifications } from "nativescript-local-notifications"`

> adding function showWithSound() function create one time notification, conti() function create continue notification after 1min, cancelAll() function cancel notification

```
showWithSound(): void { LocalNotifications.schedule([{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Sound & Badge',
      body: 'Who needs a push service anyway?',
      badge: 1,
      at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (5 * 1000)) // 5 seconds from now
    }]);

    // adding a handler, so we can do something with the received notification.. in this case an alert
    LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback(data => {
      alert({
        title: "Local Notification received",
        message: `id: '${data.id}', title: '${data.title}'.`,
        okButtonText: "ok"
      });
    });
  }

  conti(): void {
    LocalNotifications.schedule([{
      id: 2,
      title: 'Cancel me, quickly!',
      body: 'Who thought this would be a good idea!?',
      interval: 'minute',
      sound: null,
      at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (5 * 1000)), // 5 seconds from now
    }]);
  }

  cancelAll(): void {
    LocalNotifications.cancelAll();
  }
```

3) **notification.component.html file**

```
<Button type="button" text="one time notification" (tap)="showWithSound()"> </Button>
```

`<Button type="button" text="conti notification" (tap)="conti()"> </Button>`

> after all added code then any error regarding Local Notifications Plugin 
>   remove android platform and add new platform

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```